# Elixir: to assign variable in for generator(variable scope?)

Tags: for-loop, scope, elixir, variable-assignment

I'm solving, [find the largest prime factor of the number, Project Euler problem3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

Following Elixir code throw warnings, and do not evaluate in if block(assigning) I think:

```
num = 13195

range = num
         |> :math.sqrt
         |> Float.floor
         |> round

for dv <- 2..range do
  if rem(num, dv) == 0 and div(num, dv) != 1 do
    num = div(num, dv)
  end
end

num
|> IO.puts
```

Warnings are:

```
$ elixir 3.exs
warning: variable "num" is unused
  3.exs:10

warning: the result of the expression is ignored (suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
  3.exs:10

13195

$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.5.3
```

How can I update(assign) the `num`?
(following Python and Javascript codes are work for same the problem):

---

```
# 3.py
from math import ceil, sqrt

num = 600851475143

for div in range(2, ceil(sqrt(num)) + 1):
    if num%div == 0 and num/div != 1:
        num /= div

assert int(num) == 6857
```

---

```
// 3.js
var num = 600851475143;

var range = Array.from({length: Math.trunc(Math.sqrt(num))}, (x, i) => i + 2)

for (const div of range) {
  if (num%div === 0 && num/div != 1) {
      num /= div;
  }
}

var assert = require('assert');

assert(num === 6857)
```

Comment: In Elixir, variables are immutable. You can reassign a symbol to a new value, but you can't update the value of a variable you're enumerating over. Instead, you pass an updated value (which is actually a new variable) to a function. 

This is what Enum.reduce does under the hood in `praise the sun`'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually creating a new variable and shadowing the one from outer scope

You can rewrite it like this

```
num = 13195

range =
  num
  |> :math.sqrt()
  |> Float.floor()
  |> round

num =
  2..range
  |> Enum.reduce(num, fn elem, acc ->
    if rem(acc, elem) == 0 and div(acc, elem) != 1 do
      div(acc, elem)
    else
      acc
    end
  end)

IO.puts num
```

More on shadowing:

> ```
> +------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Top level                                                  |
> |                                                            |
> |  +------------------------+     +------------------------+ |
> |  | Module                 |     | Module                 | |
> |  |                        |     |                        | |
> |  | +--------------------+ |     | +--------------------+ | |
> |  | | Function clause    | |     | | Function clause    | | |
> |  | |                    | |     | |                    | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | |     | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | | | Comprehension  | | |     | | | Comprehension  | | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | |     | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | | ... | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | | | Anon. function | | |     | | | Anon. function | | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | |     | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | |     | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | | | Try block      | | |     | | | Try block      | | | |
> |  | | +----------------+ | |     | | +----------------+ | | |
> |  | +--------------------+ |     | +--------------------+ | |
> |  +------------------------+     +------------------------+ |
> |                                                            |
> +------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> Any variable in a nested scope whose name coincides with a variable from the surrounding scope will shadow that outer variable. In other words, the variable inside the nested scope temporarily hides the variable from the surrounding scope, but does not affect it in any way.

[source](http://elixir-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical/scoping.html)

Comment: Thanks! Learned using reduce for updating. Btw, Elixir variables are bounded in `for`(or include all do ~ end) scope?